# Existence of nonsimilar matrix with same properties.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization

I wanted to know Is there exist 2 nonsimilar matrices with all algebraic properties same?

I think there exists such pair as otherwise there we necessary sufficient condition of diagonalisibily using above.

Please Help me to construct an example

I can construct 2 nonsimilar matrices with same minimal polynomial,characteristics polynomial eigenvalue.
Example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$,

$$B= \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$

Here Eigen values of both are A and B are 1 Minimal Polynomial is $(x-1)^3$ and Char Polynomial is $(x-1)^7$
Eigenvectros of A is $\{e_1,e_4,e_6\}$ and that of B $\{e_1,e_4,e_7\}$

But I do not know how to convert above matrices by permutation to have same eigenvectors
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you familiar with Jordan normal form?  And how it relates to minimal polynomial?

Comment: Dear Sir I know that if both matrices have same jordan form then they have same minimal polynomial .But i need it must have same eigenvector that I do not know how to construct.I can construct nonsimilar matrix with same minimal polynomial charcterstics polynomial,eigenvalue but unable control eigenvector.Please Help me

Comment: Eigenvectors are extremely easy to control.  The Jordan form only controls how *many* eigenvectors you’ll get for each eigenvalue, but you can otherwise choose the eigenvectors arbitrarily by applying a similarity transform (i.e. choosing the $P$ matrix).  You should edit the question to show your work up to this point.

Comment: For instance, for a matrix in Jordan form the eigenvectors are just principal vectors like $(0,0,1,0,0,0)$.  You only have to permute rows and columns to get them to match another matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Eric is hinting at something like this: $$\pmatrix{0&1&&&&&\cr&0&1&&&&\cr&&0&0&&&\cr&&&0&1&&\cr&&&&0&0&\cr&&&&&0&1\cr&&&&&&0\cr}$$ and $$\pmatrix{0&1&&&&&\cr&0&1&&&&\cr&&0&0&&&\cr&&&0&1&&\cr&&&&0&0&1\cr&&&&&0&0\cr&&&&&&0\cr}$$

If I've done it right, both have characteristic polynomial $t^7$, minimal polynomial $t^3$, and eigenvectors $(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,0,1,0,0,0)$, and $(0,0,0,0,0,1,0)$, but they aren't similar.